# Trying to get drupal's Code Sniffer working with Sublime Text 2, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, drupal, phpcodesniffer

I followed [this](http://mark.shropshires.net/blog/drupal-code-sniffer-setup-sublime-text-2-os-x) tutorial, but when I hit cmd-B in Sublime, I get this error:

> Warning: include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpcs on line 31
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpcs on line 31
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI' not found in /usr/local/bin/phpcs on line 34

I'm just working with general PHP files, not in MAMP or anything, and I just want to check if they follow the drupal coding standards. What's going wrong?

Comment: did you followed this guide? http://drupal.org/node/1419988

Comment: Yes. I did all right up until the Installing on Windows/XAMP section.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882467/cant-include-pear-package-that-definitely-exists-and-is-installed